# Negative definiteness of a block matrix

Tags: matrices

There is a block matrix,
\begin{align}
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C & I
\end{array}\right)\quad\text{where}\quad A<0
\end{align}
I am curious whether the matrix $M$ is negative definite or not. 
If $M$ becomes negative definite, what assumptions are required?

Comment: $M$ cannot be negative definite because of the identity matrix on the diagonal. It is *indefinite*. Note also that $M$ should be symmetric (C=B^T) to talk about definiteness.

Comment: take a look at Schur's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the element  $M_{11}$(also called the first minor of the matrix) is positive, which is stated in the question. 
In order for this matrix to be negative definite, the determinant (or equivalently the second minor $M_{22}$ needs to be positive. If it is zero then the matrix is negative semidefinite. If it's, on the other hand, negative then it is indefinite.
$$M_{22}= det \left ( M \right )=AI-CB$$
Now you see that the definiteness  depends on the values of A,B and I.